Failed to authenticate the user NT Authority\Anonymous Logon in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated)
I've set up an Azure SQL Server and am attempting to use Microsoft Entra Integrated authentication. However, when I try to connect via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and select Entra Integrated for authentication, I encounter an error.
Using Microsoft Entra MFA works with no issues.
Error message:
===================================
Failed to authenticate the user NT Authority\Anonymous Logon in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated).
Error code 0xintegrated_windows_auth_not_supported_managed_user
Integrated Windows Auth is not supported for managed users. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-iwa for details.  (Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider)
For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-0-database-engine-error
Server Name: db.database.windows.net
Error Number: 0
Severity: 11
State: 0
Procedure: AcquireToken
Program Location:
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.GetFedAuthToken(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OnFedAuthInfo(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo originalNetworkAddressInfo, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

 at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)

 at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateSqlConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IDbConnection dbConnection, IServerType server)

 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)

 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()

Your help would be much appreciated.

The error message “Login failed for user ‘NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON’” typically indicates an issue with Kerberos delegation or Service Principal Name (SPN) configuration for SQL Server.
To resolve this error, ensure that the Service Principal Names (SPNs) for both SQL Server instances are correctly registered. For more details about the “Login failed for user” error, refer to this link.
I used the MSDOC to configure Microsoft Entra authentication for Azure SQL Database and SQL Managed Instance.
For setting up Microsoft Entra authentication for SQL Server, refer to this tutorial using multifactor Microsoft Entra authentication.
I followed this link to use Microsoft.SqlClient.Data to connect to Azure SQL Database with Microsoft Entra multifactor authentication in .NET.
    var connectionString = @"Server=<your server>.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Interactive; Database=<your database>";

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection successful!");

            // Your SQL operations here
            string query = "select * from [dbo].[Books]";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader[0]);
                        Console.WriteLine(reader[1]);
                        Console.WriteLine(reader[2]);
                        Console.WriteLine(reader[3]);
                        Console.WriteLine(reader[4]);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}




Output:

Azure Sql Server Output:

